# android activity singleTop, onPause() then unexpected onCreate()

Tags: android, android-activity

well here's a weird one that's been making my eyes cross for a few hours.

please be patient, much of this is explanation.

i have an Activity.  its launchMode is singleTop.  i've got log statements in it so i can see which of the various lifecycle routines are being executed.

i start said Activity and it goes thru

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

the Activity is passed an Intent and the Intent is picked up by something that runs after onResume()

i think the following happen because my Activity gets pushed to the background because of an incoming cell phone call.

```
onPause() <---- since i HAVE NOT pressed Back indicating the activity is over this SAVES STATE
```

while i'm out of the app running my Activity, the OS needs more resources and that, i think, explains why this is called:

```
onStop()
```

then i navigate back to my app and i see this runs:

```
onNewIntent()
```

ok.  i think i understand this - it runs because that's how the OS communicates with an Activity defined as singleTop after its already been started.  am i right?

then i see

```
 onRestart()
 onStart()
 onResume()
```

which is all standard stuff

then i hit Home, prior to running something that will consume a lot of resources and force the OS to kill my app

i see

```
onPause() <- saves state
onStop()
```

when i navigate back i see

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

which makes sense because my Activity was killed and i've navigated back. onCreate() is how you start something that wasn't already running (since it was killed).  onStart() and on Resume() are part of the normal lifecycle.

so i hit HOME again, the OS kills my app

```
onPause() <- saves state
onStop()
```

and i go back to it

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

HERE'S WHERE THINGS GET ODD:

i'm done with my Activity and i hit Back to leave it

```
onPause()  <------- i detect Back was pressed so i DO NOT save state and delete previously saved state
onCreate() <------- say what?
```

i expected to see the standard stuff that comes after onPause() like onStop() and onDestroy() but for some reason that doesn't happen.

the OS runs my onCreate() again but since the Activity is over and i tried leaving by hitting the Back key this was all detected in onPause() and NO STATE WAS SAVED.

onCreate() thinks its running all over again.  but there is no Intent data and

since the Intent delivered in the first onCreate() is gone and i've deleted all saved state onCreate() quickly succumbs to a NullPointerException

what on earth is going on?  more importantly, how do i make my Activity die and stay dead?

EDIT 1:

some new information just came to light.
in the problematic onPause()/onCreate() sequence i describe above i logged the value of isFinished().  it shows

```
onPause() - isFinishing() is true.  good that is what i expect.
onCreate() - isFinishing() is false!?
```

so the OS really is truly staring my Activity again.  but why?

Comment: onStop() is triggered when your Activity is not surfaced, i know you know that, back to you, do you trigger other activities from this activity? what are their launch mode?

Comment: @Elitz - trigger how?  with startActivity()?  there are startActivity() calls in the code but NOT in the execution path i described